# Python histogram delta question ( no graph )

Tags: python, histogram

i have a problem in which i have the histogram numbers below

```
    col val 
    a    10
    b    20
    c    50
    d    90
```

as we can see the value at a is 10 and increased to b by 10. so there is an increase. i need an expected output like

```
    col val increase
    a   10   0
    b   20   10 ( b-a) 
    c   50   30 ( c- b)
    d   90   40  ( d -c )
```

means each row will calculate difference from it's previous value. please could you help me for the python script on the same.

Answer (score 0):

i think i hv found ans 
df['increase'] = df['val'] - df['val'].shift(1)

thanks. will check if i can close the comment